# How to check if wiringPiSetup() was run

Tags: pi-4, wiringpi

I am working on a C++ project using several objects that use wiringPi. When I initialize the objects each runs `wiringPiSetup()` in their constructor. If I test the objects individually all o them work. But when I combine them into the main project they will not read `digitalRead()` anymore.

I found out that `wiringPiSetup()` should only be run once. Is there an elegant way to check if the setup is already completed without writing my own flag and somehow pass it to all objects?

Answer (score 1):

It is standard programming practice to check if includes/initialisers have been used which can easily be done with #ifdef directives.

Frankly including wiringPiSetup() in a constructor is poor practice - if you want to use it include ONCE in your main code (as I think Gordon's comment indicates).
If you have multiple modules use #ifdef directives in each to implement once.

NOTE WiringPi is deprecated and is unlikely to be included in future Raspberry Pi OS

Answer (score 0):

The first setup sets the wiringPiSetuped flag which is checked at each invocation.

From that it can be seen that it does not matter (any more) if setup is called multiple times.

The relevant part of the wiringPi code is as follows.

```c
int wiringPiSetup (void)
{
  int   fd ;
  int   model, rev, mem, maker, overVolted ;

// It's actually a fatal error to call any of the wiringPiSetup routines more than once,
//  (you run out of file handles!) but I'm fed-up with the useless twats who email
//  me bleating that there is a bug in my code, so screw-em.

  if (wiringPiSetuped)
    return 0 ;

  wiringPiSetuped = TRUE ;
```